# UnauthorizedAccessException behavior in ASP.NET Core policy based authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, error-handling, .net-5

I have a simple ASP.NET Core API (.net 5) application with security configured like this:

```
    services.AddControllers(options =>
        options.Filters.Add(new MyExceptionFilter()));
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)     
       .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AAD"));

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy =>
           policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
               context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "myclaim" && c.Value == "myvalue")));
    });
```

The policy is then applied to a controller:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Policy = "MyPolicy")]
    public class DefaultController : ControllerBase {}
```

When a token has no required claim the framework throws `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: IDW10201: Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token. 
   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<<AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiImplementation>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Which is OK. What's not OK is that it then translates to HTTP 500 although I expect HTTP 403. The problem is that standard exception filters (inherited from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute`) don't catch it, probably because it's happening too early in the pipeline.

Why is it designed this way? How can I map exceptions from the authentication phase to whatever I need?

Comment: could you show your `AddJwtBearer` step ? The exception was throw on `AuthenticationMiddleware`, it's not even reach `AuthorizationMiddleware`, which authorization policy doesn't take place yet... kinda weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... I got that here. Thanks for updated the code, couldn't trace back this deep without it.

The code make use of `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi`, which belongs to `Microsoft.Identity.Web` package. And behind the screen, make use of `JwtBearerOptions` and `JwtBearerHandler`.

On the config of `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi`, `JwtBearerEvents` was hard code to require scope and role claims, as you can see [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/WebApiExtensions/MicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L241).

`http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope` and `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` was specific for .net world, and `scp` and `roles` for Oauth standard world. The content of Jwt token input must have at least one of four of these scopes, otherwise, the exception would raise (as `JwtBearerEvents` call to validate [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L149), that directly point to [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerEvents.cs#L57), which was hard-coded as the first link above.)

The point is, the exception would throw on `AuthenticationMiddleware`, which was pretty high on our pipeline, catch `UnauthorizedAccessException` here to return 403 might swallow any custom logic that make use of `UnauthorizedAccessException` we would like to throw from application logic (in my case, I use this kind of exception in my own project).

So the most suitable one would be ensure that the jwt token input have one of four scope as I mention above (it's required by `Microsoft.Identity.Web` package itself). Or make use of a middleware placing above `AuthenticationMiddleware`, and catch `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception only with message contain `IDW10201`, then write the response back from 500 to 403. (I still prefer Exception filter below Controller level, as I can separate which exception come from my logic, or from somewhere else).